# modify-syntax-entry is not loaded in emacs init?

Tags: emacs

Since I don't want underline char `_` to break a word, I put the script:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

in the Emacs init file. The purpose is that for words like `test_test`, to double click the word will select the whole word before and after `_`.

But for some reason, the script is not working in initialization.
If I run

```
M-x eval-buffer
```

Then it will start to be effective. Why is that?

BTW, all other setups in init are working well, it is only the `modify-syntax-entry` that requires an additional evaluation after the initial launch.

Comment: Every buffer has its own syntax table. The emacs init file is run with a temporary buffer as the current buffer.

Comment: Read https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I've read through the emacswiki, but I still don't understand how to hack it. Would you mind explaining a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com might be a better place to get help with this.

Answer (score 3):

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Basics](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Basics.html).  There you will see this:

> Typically, each major mode has its own syntax table, which
>   it installs in all buffers that use that mode.  For example, the
>   variable `emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table` holds the syntax table used by
>   Emacs Lisp mode, and `c-mode-syntax-table` holds the syntax table used
>   by C mode.  Changing a major mode’s syntax table alters the syntax in
>   all of that mode’s buffers, as well as in any buffers subsequently put
>   in that mode.

You need to change the syntax table of the **current buffer** (which will
typically make the change for all buffers in the same mode).

The current syntax table, that is, the **syntax table of the current buffer**, is returned by function **`syntax-table`**.  So that is what you pass to `modify-syntax`:

```el
;; Modify the CURRENT syntax table (not `standard-syntax-table').
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (syntax-table))
```

Function `syntax-table` is described in the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Table Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html).

However, you seem to want to make this change for ***all*** buffers, whatever the mode.  Is that right?  That's probably a mistake.

*What you should probably do is this:*

1. *Decide which modes* you want to modify this way.
2. For those modes, put the call to `modify-syntax-entry` in a function that you *add to the mode hook* of each of those modes (using `add-hook`).

For example, to modify the syntax of, say, `foo-mode`:

```
 (defun my-syntax () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (syntax-table)))
 (add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'my-syntax)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Every buffer has its own syntax table, which is usually dependent on the major mode of the buffer. When you run your code in the Emacs init file, it just modifies the syntax table of the temporary buffer that's used while loading the file, not your regular buffers.

Most syntax tables inherit from the standard syntax table, so you can make your change to that table by giving another argument to `modify-syntax-entry`:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (standard-syntax-table))
```

Comment: Then I suggest you ask in Emacs.SE.

Comment: Note that it won't work if you go into a mode that overrides the standard syntax entry for `_`.

Comment: It's much better to modify specific modes' tables.

Answer (score 2):

A sideways solution: replace your problematic line of code with

```
(global-superword-mode 1)
```

This will tell Emacs that you like your "word movements" to actually operate on *identifiers* rather than what Emacs traditionally defines as *words*.  The advantage is that it keeps the normal definition of words for internal use, so it should in theory break less code than your approach.